# Issue with sklearn k nearest neighbors

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, duplicates, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I wonder if there is a way to force sklearn NearestNeighbors algorithm, to take into account the order of a point in the input array, when there are duplicate points.

To illustrate:

```
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
>>> import numpy as np

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X)
indices                                           
>>>> array([[0, 1],
     [1, 0],
     [2, 1],
     [3, 4],
     [4, 3],
     [5, 4]])
```

Because the query set matches the training set, the nearest neighbor of each point is the point itself, at a distance of zero. If however, I allow for duplicate points in X, the algorithm, understandably, does not distinguish between the duplicates:

```
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1],[3, 2],[-1,-1],[-1,-1]])
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='auto').fit(X)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X)
indices 
>>>> array([[6, 0],
   [1, 0],
   [2, 1],
   [3, 4],
   [4, 3],
   [5, 4],
   [6, 0],
   [6, 0]])
```

Ideally, I would like the last output to be something like:

```
    >>>> array([[0, 6],
   [1, 0],
   [2, 1],
   [3, 4],
   [4, 3],
   [5, 4],
   [6, 0],
   [7, 6]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot do that, since from the [ref](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) we got:

> Warning: Regarding the Nearest Neighbors algorithms, if two neighbors,
>   neighbor **k+1** and **k**, have identical distances but different labels, the
>   results will depend on the ordering of the training data.